# Branching Paths Problem

Tags: vectors, recreational-mathematics

I was drawing some shapes during class, and I came across the following problem. If one takes steps of constant length, and one must deviate a constant angle $\alpha$ from one's previous step either left or right on the next step, for an angle $\alpha$ what is the set of all possible points I can reach on my path? A point is defined as the end of a step.

Here is a poorly drawn diagram of the problem:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

NOTE: This is perhaps assuming you don't have to turn every time, i.e. you can just travel one unit in the current direction. It depends on the angle. If the angle is $2 \pi, \pi, \pi / 2, 3 \pi / 2$,$2 \pi / 3$,$4 \pi / 3$, $\pi / 3$ or $5 \pi / 3$ then the set of points you can reach will form what's called a "lattice," and "regular tiling" which you can look up but it basically means your points are regularly spaced from one another and form a regular tiling pattern that has some form of rotational symmetry (and for $2\pi$ or $\pi$, it will be a regular pattern along a horizontal line). If the angle is $\alpha \pi$ where $\alpha$ is irrational, then I believe the set of points is hard to describe with some form of closed form parametric formula or nice description, but the set of points you can reach should be dense in the plane (but not all the plane, because the set of points you can reach is countable whereas the set of points in the plane is uncountable). If $\alpha$ is rational not one of the values I described earlier, then I think it's more complicated, and the set of points you can reach may not dense. Maybe someone can leave a comment and then I can update with a more definitive descriptive answer for that case.

Comment: Ah, I should edit the question. The person traveling must turn every step, but I think your answer still applies. I am interested in investigating the cases where the angle is irrational. I'm also wondering if it's possible to return to the point you started at (0, 0) with irrational angles. With a lattice structure you can get from basically any point to another, but I'm unsure of the structure with an irrational angle.

Comment: @SullyChen Sorry I'll try to update taking into consideration that you always have to turn. However I do know that if your angle is $\alpha \pi$ where $\alpha$ is irrational then it will be impossible to return to any point you have previously visited.

Comment: @SullyChen Also I should say, I'm not sure if the assumption that you have to turn every time changes anything I said. So for now I'll just say "This is PERHAPS assuming that you don't have to turn every time."

Comment: You say it is impossible to return to (0, 0) when α is irrational, but could there exist a path or pattern than gets closer and closer to (0, 0) the longer you travel it, sort of like a limit?

Comment: For all rational angles (that is, rational multiples of $\pi$), always turning in one direction should sketch out a (possibly star) polygon that will always take you back to the origin. This is easy to see for angles of the form $\frac\pi n$ but I believe it's relatively straightforward for all angles of the form $\frac pq\pi$.

Comment: I see now, that makes sense.